# Swift UINavigation Bottom Line and Shadow Remove without Navbar Color Change

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am trying to remove bottom line and shadow from `UINavigationBar` using **iOS 13 - Swift 5**. Here, Before **iOS 13 - Swift 5**, I used below code for removing bottom line and shadow without changing navigation bar color. Now, It is not showing `NavigationBar` color (I already set Bar Color and Background Color) also disabled Transulent.

**Code:**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

How to fix this? Need to remove bottom line shadow and also want to give NavigationBar Colour.

Comment: This has nothing to do with _language_ ("Swift 5"). It has to do, with anything, with iOS system version. Navigation bars look and behave differently in iOS 13. Are you using iOS 13? If so, you need to use the new UINavigationBarAppearance class.

Comment: iOS 12 I am using @matt

Comment: @jamKu did you find a solution ? I'v e got the same problem, the shadow is hidden on iOS 12 but not on iOS 13 :/

Comment: @matt Do you know how to remove the shadow using the new `UINavigationBarAppearance`?

Comment: It's a shame that some people downvote questions just because they don't understand them.

Comment: @ataravati "Do you know how to remove the shadow" That sounds like a different question. Could you ask it as a different question?

Comment: @matt I already figured out how to do that.

Comment: @ataravati Excellent! Could you delete the comment asking how? I'll delete my comments too. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

For me, it only worked after changing the following (>= iOS13)

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
navBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This was what worked for me. I hadn't noticed that there was both `standardAppearance` and `scrollEdgeAppearance`

Comment: Worked for me for iOS 15 

Comment: worked!!! with iOS 15 and xcode 14.1 and swiftui view is presented threw hosting controller

Answer (score 8):

If you are using iOS 13, you can't remove the shadow by setting the `shadowImage` to `UIImage()`. You'll have to also set the `shadowColor` to `nil` or `UIColor.clear`.

Comment: I was looking for answer for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: @MehulThakkar Then, you’re doing something wrong. iOS 13 is iOS 13 for everyone.

Comment: Thanks @ataravati for the response, i have tried for `shadowColor`, it didn't worked, then i tried `shadowImage` way, it worked. I have checked that i am running the code on iOS 13, also i am using Xcode 11.2.1.

Answer (score 6):

**XCODE 13 - iOS 15**

For Xcode 13 and targeting iOS ver 13 and above you can use this code:

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
                appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
                appearance.backgroundColor = .red // Your color
                appearance.shadowColor = .clear
                appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
                navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
                navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this, I added in viewDidLoad. It works for me.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working for iOS13 and Swift

```swift
let barAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
barAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
```

Comment: configureWithTransparentBackground works for me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below Code working for me

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 15 and in order to fix wrong navigation bar color glitch, you have to use relatively newest API of UINavigationBarAppearance and tiny but important moment - to refresh navigation bar if it's already on the screen. Below is the full code:

```swift
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
      let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
      appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
      appearance.backgroundColor = <#your_color#>
      appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
      appearance.shadowColor = .clear
      UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
      UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
      UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
      UINavigationBar.appearance().compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

      // force refresh navigation bar background color
      isNavigationBarHidden = true
      isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do with UINavigationBarAppearance you can do with this.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
appearance.shadowColor = UIColor.clear
appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```