# How to remove this black line in swift5

Tags: ios, swift, ipados

[image]

I don't know how to remove this black line.

Comment: You use a NavigationController, but don't want to show it (well, the NavigationBar)?

Comment: Yeah I don’t want to show it only for this view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56955774/1801544 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line/19227158#19227158 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the Controller Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
}
```